# Strange "Unrecognized Selector" Issue

Tags: objective-c

I am learning to use the new Storyboards feature in iOS 5 for a basic list view -> detail view nav-based app.  To eliminate complexity, I am just mocking up my data in an array.  The array is of a custom class ("VehicleModel") with several properties and an initializer.

Most of the properties are just NSStrings, but one is a pointer to an "VehicleEngineInfo" object, which has a single property ("engineType") and an initializer:

```
-(id)initWithType:(NSString*)type {
  if(self = [super init]) {
    [self setEngineType: type];
  }
  return self;
}
```

I have a more specific VehicleEngineElectric class that extends VehicleEngineInfo and adds a property ("cellCountMask") and has its own initializer:

```
-(id)initWithCellCountMask:(Byte)mask {
  if(self = [super initWithType:ENGINETYPE_ELECTRIC]) {
    [self setCellCountMask:mask];
  }
  return self;
}
```

When I create a new instance of "VehicleModel" for the data array, I call the initializer like this:

```
VehicleModel *m1 = [[VehicleModel alloc] initWithName:@"name" Brand:@"brand" Model:@"model" Type:TYPE_CAR Status:STATUS_ACTIVE EngineInfo:[[VehicleEngineElectric alloc] initWithCellCountMask:0x01] Image:IMAGE_CAR];
```

If i immediately try to read back the engineType property ([[m1 engineInfo]engineType]), it works fine.  When I try to read the same engineType property in a different method (such as prepareForSegue:), I get an NSInvalidArgumentException with the lovely "unrecognized selector sent to instance..." message.  I can read back any of the other properties on the VehicleInfo object just fine - only the VehicleEngineInfo property causes a problem.

My first though was that this was a memory management problem (retain/release) but I have ARC enabled so that shouldn't be it.  Why does the engineType property get lost when I leave the method in which it was created?

UPDATE:
The @property declarations look like this...

On VehicleEngineInfo:

```
@property (nonatomic, assign) NSString* engineType;
```

On VehicleEngineElectric:

```
@property (nonatomic, assign) Byte cellCountMask;
```

On the main VehicleModel:

```
@property (nonatomic, assign) VehicleEngineInfo* engineInfo;
@property (nonatomic, assign) NSString* name;
@property (nonatomic, assign) NSString* brand;
@property (nonatomic, assign) NSString* model;
@property (nonatomic, assign) NSString* type;
@property (nonatomic, assign) NSString* status;
@property (nonatomic, assign) VehicleEngineInfo* engineInfo;
@property (nonatomic, assign) UIImage* image;
```

The @synthesize statements just have the names of the properties, so theres nothing special about them.

The error message is this:

> 2011-11-14 23:33:42.951 TableTest[15640:fb03] -[__NSArrayI engineType]: unrecognized selector sent to instance 0x6a89d90
>   2011-11-14 23:33:42.953 TableTest[15640:fb03] *** Terminating app due to uncaught exception 'NSInvalidArgumentException', reason: '-[__NSArrayI engineType]: unrecognized selector sent to instance 0x6a89d90'
>   *** First throw call stack:
>   (0x129b052 0x174cd0a 0x129cced 0x1201f00 0x1201ce2 0x35ff 0x705e1e 0x3716d9 0x371952 0xbf986d 0x126f966 0x126f407 0x11d27c0 0x11d1db4 0x11d1ccb 0x1f53879 0x1f5393e 0x2e1a9b 0x24b8 0x2415)
>   terminate called throwing an exceptionCurrent language:  auto; currently objective-c

Comment: Can we see the `@property` declaration, and `@synthesize` statement, for both engineInfo and engineType?

Comment: You're not showing us enough of the code to diagnose the problem.  Show us the property declarations, and the full error message, which will tell us what selector wasn't recognized.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It is unusual to have object (as opposed to scalar) properties of the `assign` type. I would expect to see them as `retain` or `copy`.

What it looks like is that your `engineInfo` property is getting released and the memory is re-assigned to an `NSArray` somewhere, you are then interrogating the object and getting the unrecognized selector error since your pointer is now pointing at a totally different object.

Comment: Setting it to retain fixed the problem.  Thank you much!

Answer (score 1):

Generally speaking,
Types of Object use: **retain**
Type of NSString uses: **copy**
Others like int, float, etc(and even the delegate) use **assign**
Try @jrturton's suggestion, but not sure if it is the really reason that causes your problem.

Comment: Thanks for the reference of what to use and when.  I need to brush up on what exactly these mean.